# How to set system-wide DNS server settings on macOS, not for each network?

Tags: macos, network, dns

I'd like to set one DNS server IP that my Mac should always use, but currently I have to repeat the same process every time I connect to a new network:

System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced > DNS > "+" etc.

Is it possible to set it once and forget it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Secure DNS on MacOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365531/how-to-use-secure-dns-on-macos)